# matplotlib only show points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem to plot lines and points in the next code, when I use `plt.plot` with x4,y4 only show me the points, I would like to know what's the problem. I am using python 3.52 and wingware python IDE 101 5.1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain



od = float(input("Ingrese el diametro externo: "))
id = float(input("Ingrese el diametro interno: "))
Yp = int(input("Ingrese la cedencia de la tuberia: "))
DF2 = float(input("Ingrese factor de diseño triaxial: "))

area=((od**2)-(id**2))*0.7854
Fy=area*Yp
Fy=int(Fy)

Fy2=-(1.16*Fy)
Fy2=int(Fy2)
Fy3=(1.16*Fy)
Fy3=int(Fy3)
t = ((od - id) / 2)



s= (od/t)
s=float(s)

ca=Fy2


c_com=range(Fy2,0,2000)
c_ten=range(0,Fy3,2000)


for ca in chain(c_com,c_ten):


   ca1 = (ca / area) 
   BB = (ca1 / Yp)
   cc = ((1 - (0.75 * ((BB) ** (2)))))
   if cc<0:
      cc = 0
   d = (((cc) **(0.5)) - (0.5 * BB))
   d1 = (((cc) **(0.5)) + (0.5 * BB))
   Ype= d * (Yp)
   Ype1=d1 * (Yp)

   a = 2.8762 + (0.10679* (0.00001)*Ype )+(0.21301 * (0.0000000001) * ((Ype) ** (2)))- (0.53132 * (1E-16) * ((Ype) **(3)))

   b = 0.026233 + (0.50609 * (0.000001) * Ype)
   c = -465.93 + (0.030867 * Ype) - (0.10483 * (0.0000001) * ((Ype) ** (2))) + (0.36989 * (0.0000000000001) * ((Ype) ** (3)))
   if c < -20000 :
      break
   O = (b / a)
   f = ((46.95 * 1000000) * (((3 * O) / (2 + O)) ** (3))) / ((Ype * (((3 * O) / (2 + O) - O))) * ((1 - ((3 * O) / (2 + O)))) ** (2))

   g = f * O


   L = (c/ Ype)
   s1 = ((((a - 2) + (8 * (b+ L))) ** (0.5)) + (a - 2)) / (2 * (b + L))
   s1=abs(s1)
   s2 = (Ype * (a - f)) / (c + (Ype * (b - g)))
   s2=float(s2)
   s3 = (2 + (b / a)) / (3 * b / a)
   s3=float(s3)  


   Pc1 = 2 * Ype * ((s - 1) / (s * s))
   Pc2 = (Ype * ((a / s) - b)) - c 
   Pc3 = (Ype * ((f / s) - g))
   Pc4 = (46.95 * 1000000) / (s * ((s - 1) ** 2))


   Pc=0  
   Pc=int(Pc)


   if s<s1 : 
      Pc= Pc1

   elif s1<s<s2:
      Pc = Pc2
   elif s2 < s < s3:
      Pc= Pc3
   elif s>s3:
      Pc = Pc4

   Pe=0
   Pe = (0.875 * 2 * Ype1 * t) / od
   Pe=int(Pe)
   Pc=int(Pc) 
   if 0<ca<Fy-7000:
      coo=((-Pc/1))
      caa=(ca)
      x4=(caa,Fy)
      y4=(coo,0)
      plt.plot(x4,y4,"ro-",markersize=3)
      plt.show()


   if ca==0:
      co=str((-Pc))
      Pb=str((Pe))
      x3=[0,-Fy,-Fy,-Fy,0,Fy,Fy]
      y3=[co,co,0,Pb,Pb,Pb,0]
      plt.plot(x3,y3,color='y',linewidth=2)
```

Comment: is all of that math necessary to demonstrate the problem? Distill this down to an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Move `plt.show` outside the `if` clause and put it at the very end of the code, or at the end of the `for` loop.

When you call `plt.plot`, a new plot is constructed, but not shown, so no image is drawn, but the structure is already created. You can call `plt.plot` many times with new data, which will accumulate and when you call `show`, will result in many graphs drawn on the same image.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried what you said but the plot show me many lines together,no just one line with all the points.

Comment: @MIGUELTORO, then try to move the call to `show` outside the loop.

Comment: i did it but nothing change

Comment: @MIGUELTORO, can you please show an example output plot?

Comment: @MIGUELTORO, this link redirects me to http://example.com for some reason.

Comment: @MIGUELTORO, so you want to plot only the dots? Or only the last values of `x3` and `y3`? Or what? I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, to be honest.

Comment: i want to plot the dots and the lines together, ploting x3,y3 and x4,y4, as you can se when i plot x3,y3 there is a line that conect the dots, thats fine, the problem is in x4,y4, that dont show me all the dots conect by only one line.